role="option" with aria-selected Not Announced Correctly in VoiceOver
I am implementing an accessible listbox with role="listbox" for the parent container and role="option" for each item and aria-selected to indicate the selected state. However, VoiceOver does not announce the selected state when selecting the option.
<div role="listbox" aria-label="Options">
  <div role="option" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">Option 1</div>
  <div role="option" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Option 2</div>
  <div role="option" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Option 3</div>
</div>

Issue:
VoiceOver is announcing the selected option as selected on first time but when i select the another option it does not announcing the option as selected. Video example
And when i navigating through options, it announces
Option 1 not selected
in addition to this it also announces
You are on a selectable (null), inside a listbox
how do i prevent the VoiceOver from saying null?
Here's the sample codepen link
I'm expecting VoiceOver to say selected state when selecting the another option

I think VO also expects aria-activedescendant to work correctly.

@QuentinC aria-activedescendant can be used as an alternative to moving the DOM focus between option elements during keyboard navigation. However, I don't require this approach here.

Maybe the variant where the selection follows focus is better supported by VO?
